# ConstraintLayout - element that fills remaining height does not resize

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I'm working on a simple chatting app, which has a recyclerView to display messages and a LinearLayout to contain controls for sending new messages. The controls should take as much space as needed (when writing multiple lines of text, it gets bigger) and the recyclerView should take the rest.

I have encountered these issues with my code (see bellow):

1. When the keyboard pops up, the recyclerView is overlaped (should be resized to fit the remaining space)
   [Overlap when keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ZfP.png)
2. When writing more lines of text, the recyclerView is again overlaped (should be resized to fit the remaining space)
   [Overlap when wirting longer text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7GiJ.png)

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
           android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:id="@+id/recycler1"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/line"
               app:gone="@{!viewModel.loaded}"
               app:itemBinding="@{viewModel.itemBinding}"
               app:items="@{viewModel.items}" />

           <!-- A horizontal line between the chatbox and RecyclerView -->
           <View
               android:id="@+id/line"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="2dp"
               android:background="#dfdfdf"
               android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chatControls"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/chatControls"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:minHeight="48dp"
               android:background="#ffffff"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/messageEdit"
                   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:maxLines="6"
                   android:text="@={viewModel.messageText}"
                   android:hint="@string/hint_write" />

               <ImageButton
                   android:id="@+id/chatSendButton"
                   android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                   android:clickable="true"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                   android:layout_width="48dp"
                   android:layout_height="48dp"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                   android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.sendMessage()}" />

           </LinearLayout>

       </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the right behaviour by setting *stackFromEnd* to *true* on recycler view's LinearLayoutManager.